# How can I return from `channel.write` method that hangs indefinitely

Tags: rust

I'm unable to getout after writing to stdin of the server.

Here's the example code that uses `ssh2 crate`:

```rust
// creates channel struct from session 
// channel: https://docs.rs/ssh2/latest/ssh2/struct.Channel.html
// session: https://docs.rs/ssh2/latest/ssh2/struct.Session.html
let mut channel = self.0.channel_session()?;

// utils::USER_ADD="useradd"
// username="some_user"
let user_add = format!("sudo -S {} {}\n", utils::USER_ADD, username);
channel.write(user_add.as_bytes())?;
channel.flush()?;
        
let mut stderr = channel.stderr();
let mut response = String::new();
        
channel.wait_close()?;
channel.exit_status()?;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're waiting for the server to close the connection, but you never tell it to. This is equivalent to login in to the server, typing the `sudo` command, and then waiting to be disconnected even though you never type `exit` or `logout`. You need to call `channel.close()` before `channel.wait_close()`.

Comment: Before even reaching to `channel.wait_close`, rust hangs at `channel.write` and doesn't goto next step i.e, `channel.flush`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `channel.shell().unwrap();` before calling write.

you can check the write window capacity with `println!("{}", channel.write_window().remaining);`

Also, you might look at using `channel.exec(<command>)` instead of using write (https://docs.rs/ssh2/latest/ssh2/index.html#run-a-command)